# confluent kafka rest avrò producer

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I use confluent kafka-rest to produce avro message, when I using the rest endpoint to consume it, the return format is like this.

```
{
    "key":null,
    "value": {ACTUAL_PAYLOAD},
    "partition":X,"offset":0
}
```

I wonder the message on in kafka is actually this format or the "key" and "partition" is added by the consumer endpoint. It will be weird if it is the former one, since in this case the response payload avro schema is not the same when you doing the produce request(schema that match ACTUAL_PAYLOAD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the later, when you produce to kafka using a client it asks for a Key and a value, the value being your payload here. The offset and partition are internal values to kafka and each record has one, its representing its position in a log. The Key is null since no key has been provided.

Comment: @Ray Don't forget to mark this answer as best answer if you have found this helpful.